# Why do we do the transformation of the variable in this proof for Poisson distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

[image]

I have 2 questions related to this question.

1. Why do we do the transformation for $i$ to $j$ in the form of $i = j+1$ in
   the 4th line of the equation? It seems to me here like it is either
   done so that we can get the equation back to original Poisson form
   with a different variable or to correct for the summation interval.
   I still cannot intuitively understand it.
2. In the 6th line, it is
   written as $\lambda\operatorname E((X+1)^{n-1}).$ But I feel like it should be
   $\lambda\operatorname E((Y+1)^{n-1})$ because did we not transform the variable in the
   4th line of the equation

Comment: You shouldn't write $x$ where you mean $X.$ Without this distinction, it becomes impossible to understand something like $\Pr(X=x). $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's to get back the Poisson form.  The second equality comes from noticing you don't need the $i=0$ term because it's zero. The fourth inequality comes from relabelling  to get back the Poisson form in $j$ instead of $i$
2. Yes, but no, but it doesn't matter.  The last equality goes from a sum over $j$ to the expectation of a Poisson random variable, and it would be true for any Poisson($\lambda$) random variable; it only depends on the distribution.  That is the equality of $E[X^n]$ and $\lambda E[(X+1)^{n+1}]$ doesn't depend on whether $X$ is the same variable in the two expressions.  **Because** it doesn't, you might award math points for using a different letter ($Y$) in the two expressions, even though it doesn't matter.  However, the fourth equality holds *exactly because* $i$ and $j+1$ are always the same, so in fact the two $X$s are the **same random variable** even though we don't need that fact, so actually you might award math points for calling them both $X$.

Comment: In this case would it not matter because X and Y have a relationship between them that we have assigned? Replacing the i with j+1 I mean.

Comment: The way I understand it is the E(X^n) has x^n in the summation term, and so it would follow that a summation term with y+1^n-1 would have that in the Expectation as well, given that X and Y are not interchangeable with each other, but X and Y+1 are.

Comment: It would never actually **matter**, because $E[(X+1)^{n-1}]$ and $E[(Y+1)^{n-1}]$ are the same thing if $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. The question is about whether it's stylistically better to use one or the other, and I don't think there's a clear advantage here.